# localhost will not show changes to website

Tags: localhost, middleman, livereload

I'm building a blog with middlemanapp, a static site generator, and have been using liveReload to automatically see changes while designing in the browser. For some reason, I cannot get localhost to update with the changes made to the html/css. I've been working in localhost for a few days now, and today is the first time this has happened. I've emptied the cache, cleaned out all cookies and browser history, and reloaded the browser but still cannot get localhost to work smoothly. What am I missing here?

Many Thanks,
David

Comment: Do you modify the same files you see in the browser?

Comment: @kol yes, and I do see changes when made, but the running localhost is much more inconsistent than my usual route of just using the livereload chrome extension.

Comment: As far as I know the chrome extension still needs to be active, as it is the one that reacts to the 'messages' send by the middleman-livereload gem.

Comment: @davidM Glad to help. I just posted it as an answer to help others, too.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the chrome extension still needs to be active, as it is the one that reacts to the 'messages' send by the middleman-livereload gem

Comment: No extensions is required to use the `middleman-livereload` extension - it brings along its own copy of the livereload.js driver.